# Angular2 Pipe can't find the name

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I made a Pipe as follow:

```ts
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { Radio } from '../../models/radio';
@Pipe({
    name: 'radioFilter'
})
export class radioFilterPipe  implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: Radio[], args: string[]): any {

        let filter = args[0].toLocaleLowerCase();
        return filter ? value.filter(radio => radio.station.text.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : value;
    }
}
```

and in my component I added the following code:

```ts
import { radioFilterPipe } from './grid.station.pipe';

// pipes: [radioFilter],
```

but I get a compile error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'radioFilter'. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per Angular 2 final release, you have to include `Pipe`, `Component`, `Directive` into `declarations` option of `NgModule` metadata.

```
@NgModule({
     declarations: [MyDirective, MyComponent, radioFilterPipe ],
     providers: [radioFilterPipe], //<-- Include pipe here if you want to use it in class as dependency
     imports: [ AppModule]
})
```

---

While including `pipe` name in `pipes` array, it should be class name `radioFilterPipe`

```
import { radioFilterPipe } from './grid.station.pipe';

@Component({
  ..,
  pipes: [radioFilterPipe ],
  ..
})
```